# How to toggle a UITextField secure text entry (hide password) in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I currently have a `UITextfield` with an eye icon in it that when pressed is supposed to toggle the secure text entry on and off.

[image: secure text entry]

I know you can check mark the "secure text entry" box in the attributes inspector but how to do it so it toggles whenever the icon is pressed?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinputtraits/1624427-securetextentry

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Use this code,

iconClick is bool variable, or you need other condition check it,

```
var iconClick = true
```

eye Action method:

```
@IBAction func iconAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    if iconClick {
        passwordTF.isSecureTextEntry = false
    } else {
        passwordTF.isSecureTextEntry = true
    }
    iconClick = !iconClick
}
```

hope its helpful

Comment: Won't this leak the password into custom keyboards when secureTextEntry is set to false?

Comment: Just a quick update, .secureTextEntry is now .isSecureTextEntry

Comment: @Iyyappan Ravi what if i have multiple password textfield to achieve the same. Do i need to add separate action for each password textfield? How do I make it  generic?

Comment: @Prabu set the action from multiple button set tag to separate method and like the same above method thats solve, hope its helpful.

Comment: FWIW, rather than maintaining your own boolean, use `isSecureTextEntry` itself. No need to create your own ivar when you already have a lovely Boolean there for you. E.g. `passwordTextField.isSecureTextEntry.toggle()` and then update the button like so `if passwordTextField.isSecureTextEntry { ... } else { ... }`.

Comment: This page has some of the worst code samples on the whole site :)

Answer (score 68):

An unintended side-effect of this is that if the user toggles to insecure, and then *back* to secure, the existing text will be cleared if the user continues typing. The cursor may also end up in the wrong position unless we reset the selected text range.

Below is an implementation that handles these cases (Swift 4)

```
extension UITextField {
    func togglePasswordVisibility() {
        isSecureTextEntry = !isSecureTextEntry

        if let existingText = text, isSecureTextEntry {
            /* When toggling to secure text, all text will be purged if the user 
             continues typing unless we intervene. This is prevented by first 
             deleting the existing text and then recovering the original text. */
            deleteBackward()

            if let textRange = textRange(from: beginningOfDocument, to: endOfDocument) {
                replace(textRange, withText: existingText)
            }
        }

        /* Reset the selected text range since the cursor can end up in the wrong
         position after a toggle because the text might vary in width */
        if let existingSelectedTextRange = selectedTextRange {
            selectedTextRange = nil
            selectedTextRange = existingSelectedTextRange
        }
    }
}
```

*This snippet is using the `replace(_:withText:)` function because it triggers the `.editingChanged` event, which happens to be useful in my application. Just setting `text = existingText` should be fine as well.*

Comment: You can also do text = nil; insertText(originalText) instead of the deleteBackward() trick which instantly shows a text selection on the latest iOS versions

Comment: You can also do let originalSelectedTextRange = selectedTextRange at the beginning of the function, to keep the original position, if the cursor is not at the end of the text

Comment: I am having an issue it's like a highlight animation when I show and hide the password.
Any idea?

Comment: @JhonnyTawk I hid that problem by changing the `tintColor` to `.clear` while the changes are being made.
 
I.e. put this at the top of the toggle method:
`let existingTintColor = tintColor`
`tintColor = .clear`
...and this at the bottom:
`DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(200)) { self.tintColor = existingTintColor }`
`

Answer (score 54):

Why to use an extra `var`. In the action method of the **eye** button just do as below

```
password.secureTextEntry = !password.secureTextEntry
```

**UPDATE**

**Swift 4.2** (as per @ROC comment)

```
password.isSecureTextEntry.toggle()
```

Comment: There is no need of extra `var` here, the answer that @Suryakant posted is the best one i think.

Comment: in swift 4.2 you can you write `password.isSecureTextEntry.toggle()`

Answer (score 38):

I wrote extension for the same. To provide Password toggle.

[image: iOS password toggle eye icons]

1. In your Assets first add images that you want for toggle.
2. Add following extension for UITextField.

   ```
   extension UITextField {
   fileprivate func setPasswordToggleImage(_ button: UIButton) {
       if(isSecureTextEntry){
           button.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_password_visible"), for: .normal)
       }else{
           button.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_password_invisible"), for: .normal)

       }
   }

   func enablePasswordToggle(){
       let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
       setPasswordToggleImage(button)
       button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -16, bottom: 0, right: 0)
       button.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(self.frame.size.width - 25), y: CGFloat(5), width: CGFloat(25), height: CGFloat(25))
       button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.togglePasswordView), for: .touchUpInside)
       self.rightView = button
       self.rightViewMode = .always
   }
   @IBAction func togglePasswordView(_ sender: Any) {
       self.isSecureTextEntry = !self.isSecureTextEntry
       setPasswordToggleImage(sender as! UIButton)
   }
   }
   ```
3. Call extension on your `UITextField` Outlet

   ```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        txtPassword.enablePasswordToggle()
        txtConfirmPassword.enablePasswordToggle()
    }
   ```

Comment: Great solution! One thing I would add is that if you press the hide password button and then type more characters, the textfield is cleared and you have to start typing it out again. I am combining this solution with @zath's solution above.

Comment: How can i continue what i typed before, when the hide password button is pressed as you meant? @JTODR

Comment: @Ali see zath's solution: `if let textRange = textRange(from: beginningOfDocument, to: endOfDocument) { replace(textRange, withText: existingText) }`

Comment: Thanks in advance @JTODR
but what do you mean by the existingText ?

Comment: @Ali If you type a password while hidden, then unhide the password to reveal the text, then hide the password again and THEN start typing again - your password field will reset and you have to start typing the entire password again. The `existingText` here is the password that you wrote before you unhide the password text.

Comment: For icons you can use: UIImage(systemName: "eye.slash.fill") and UIImage(systemName: "eye.fill")

Comment: From iOS 15.0 onwards, 'imageEdgeInsets' is deprecated.

Answer (score 25):

**Swift 4** solution

You don't need extra if statement for simple toggle isSecureTextEntry property

```
func togglePasswordVisibility() {
        password.isSecureTextEntry = !password.isSecureTextEntry
    }
```

But there is a problem when you toggle isSecureTextEntry UITextField doesn't recalculate text width and we have extra space to the right of the text. To avoid this you should replace text this way

```
func togglePasswordVisibility() {
        password.isSecureTextEntry = !password.isSecureTextEntry
        if let textRange = password.textRange(from: password.beginningOfDocument, to: password.endOfDocument) {
            password.replace(textRange, withText: password.text!)
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

**Swift 4.2**

Instead of

```
password.isSecureTextEntry = !password.isSecureTextEntry
```

you can do this

```
password.isSecureTextEntry.toggle()
```

Answer (score 12):

**Use UITextFiled rightView to show toggle button**

```
 var rightButton  = UIButton(type: .custom)
 rightButton.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:30, height:30)
 yourtextfield.rightViewMode = .always
 yourtextfield.rightView = rightButton
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! But this don't answer the question and don't solve the problem.

Answer (score 8):

If you need TextField with similar feature in multiple places its best to subclass the `UITextField` like follwing example -

```
import UIKit

class UIShowHideTextField: UITextField {

    let rightButton  = UIButton(type: .custom)

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    required override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() {
        rightButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "password_show") , for: .normal)
        rightButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toggleShowHide), for: .touchUpInside)
        rightButton.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:30, height:30)

        rightViewMode = .always
        rightView = rightButton
        isSecureTextEntry = true
    }

    @objc
    func toggleShowHide(button: UIButton) {
        toggle()
    }

    func toggle() {
        isSecureTextEntry = !isSecureTextEntry
        if isSecureTextEntry {
            rightButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "password_show") , for: .normal)
        } else {
            rightButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "password_hide") , for: .normal)
        }
    }

}
```

After which you can use it in any ViewController,

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var textField: UIShowHideTextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

**For Objective c**

set image for RightButton In viewdidload Method

```
[RightButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iconEyesOpen"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [RightButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iconEyesClose"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

and then set action method for that RightButton

```
-(IBAction)RightButton:(id)sender
{

    if (_rightButton.selected)
    {

        _rightButton.selected = NO;

        _passwordText.secureTextEntry = YES;


        if (_passwordText.isFirstResponder) {
            [_passwordText resignFirstResponder];
            [_passwordText becomeFirstResponder];
        }
    }
    else
    {

      _rightButton.selected = YES;

        _passwordText.secureTextEntry = NO;

        if (_passwordText.isFirstResponder) {
            [_passwordText resignFirstResponder];
            [_passwordText becomeFirstResponder];
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3**

```
//    MARK: Btn EyeAction
@IBAction func btnEyeAction(_ sender: Any) {

    if(iconClick == true) {
        txtPassword.isSecureTextEntry = false
        iconClick = false
    } else {
        txtPassword.isSecureTextEntry = true
        iconClick = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

## Shortest!

I think this is the shortest solution for secure entry as well as updating the picture of the button.

```
@IBAction func toggleSecureEntry(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
    textfieldPassword.isSecureTextEntry = !sender.isSelected
}
```

Assign the show/hide picture of the button according to the state selected /default , no need to create any variable or outlet.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me on Swift 5.0

```
@IBAction func changePasswordVisibility(_ sender: UIButton) {
    passwordField.isSecureTextEntry.toggle()
    if passwordField.isSecureTextEntry {
        if let image = UIImage(systemName: "eye.fill") {
            sender.setImage(image, for: .normal)
        }
    } else {
        if let image = UIImage(systemName: "eye.slash.fill") {
            sender.setImage(image, for: .normal)
        }
    }
}
```

Button attributes:

[image]

Result:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3**

```
passwordTF.isSecureTextEntry = true
passwordTF.isSecureTextEntry = false
```

Answer (score 1):

try this line:

```
@IBAction func btnClick(sender: AnyObject) {
    let btn : UIButton = sender as! UIButton
    if btn.tag == 0{
        btn.tag = 1
        textFieldSecure.secureTextEntry = NO
    }
    else{
        btn.tag = 0
        textFieldSecure.secureTextEntry = NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@IBAction func eye_toggle_clicked(sender: AnyObject)
{
    if toggleBtn.tag == 0
    {
        passwordTxt.secureTextEntry=true
        toggleBtn.tag=1
    }
    else
    {
        passwordTxt.secureTextEntry=false
        toggleBtn.tag=0
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, the property is `secureTextEntry`, but you won't find this in the `UITextField` documentation, as it is actually inherited by a `UITextField` through the `UITextInputTraits` protocol- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/UITextInputTraits/secureTextEntry

You can simply toggle this value each time your button is tapped:

```
@IBAction func togglePasswordSecurity(sender: UIButton) {
    self.passwordField.secureTextEntry = !self.passwordField.secureTextEntry
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer no need to take any bool var:

```
@IBAction func showHideAction(sender: AnyObject) {

        if tfPassword.secureTextEntry{
            tfPassword.secureTextEntry = false

        }else{
            tfPassword.secureTextEntry = true;
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to set image(visible or hide) of button of eye for different state (selected or normal)

than connect IBAction and write code like

```
@IBAction func btnPasswordVisiblityClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        (sender as! UIButton).isSelected = !(sender as! UIButton).isSelected
        if (sender as! UIButton).isSelected {
            txtfPassword.isSecureTextEntry = false
        } else {
            txtfPassword.isSecureTextEntry = true
        }
    }
```

[image: this is example of "How to set image for different state of button"]

Answer (score 1):

**In Swift 4**

```
 var iconClick : Bool!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        iconClick = true
     }


    @IBAction func showHideAction(_ sender: Any)
    {
        let userPassword = userPasswordTextFiled.text!;

        if(iconClick == true) {
            userPasswordTextFiled.isSecureTextEntry = false
            iconClick = false
        } else {
            userPasswordTextFiled.isSecureTextEntry = true
            iconClick = true
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use button with eye image
and make buttonHandler method
set Tag for button with value 1

```
-(IBAction) buttonHandlerSecureText:(UIButton *)sender{
      if(sender.tag ==1){
            [self.textField setSecureTextEntry:NO];
            sender.tag = 2;
      }
      else{
            [self.textField setSecureTextEntry:YES];
            sender.tag = 1;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assignment values change from `YES/NO` to `true/false` boolean values.

```
password.secureTextEntry = true //Visible
password.secureTextEntry = false //InVisible
```

You can try this code..
i think it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For Xamarin folks:

passwordField.SecureTextEntry = passwordField.SecureTextEntry ? passwordField.SecureTextEntry = false : passwordField.SecureTextEntry = true;

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in swift 4, tried to make a reusable code within a controller. I have set different image for buttons in storyboard as shown in the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/47669422/8334818

```
@IBAction func clickedShowPassword(_ sender: UIButton) {
        var textField :UITextField? = nil
        print("btn ",sender.isSelected.description)
        switch sender {
        case encryptOldPswdBtn:
            encryptOldPswdBtn.isSelected = !encryptOldPswdBtn.isSelected
            textField = oldPasswordTextField

        default:
          break
        }

        print("text ",textField?.isSecureTextEntry.description)
        textField?.isSecureTextEntry = !(textField?.isSecureTextEntry ?? false)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@objc func togglePasscode(){

   switch textfield.isSecureTextEntry{
      case true:
         textfield.isSecureTextEntry = false 

      case false:
         textfield.isSecureTextEntry = true 
   }
}
```

Here is a easy and more readable solution using Switch statement.

Comment: textfield.isSecureTextEntry = !textfield.isSecureTextEntry is shorter

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is simpler solution rather than creating a BOOL object globally.

```
@IBAction func passwordToggleButton(sender: UIButton) {
    let isSecureTextEntry = passwordTextField.isSecureTextEntry
    passwordTextField.isSecureTextEntry = isSecureTextEntry ? false : true
    if isSecureTextEntry {
        visibilityButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "visibility"), for: .normal)
    } else {
        visibilityButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "visibility_off"), for: .normal)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

only add this line into your code replace you TextField name with "textfield" Done:
you need to change the isSecureTextEntry propertity to change true for password type textFiled like ......

```
textField.isSecureTextEntry = true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
    if(sender.isSelected == true) {
        RegPasswordField.isSecureTextEntry = false
        sender.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(systemName: "eye.fill"), for: .normal)
            } else {
                RegPasswordField.isSecureTextEntry = true
                sender.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(systemName: "eye"), for: .normal)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5** Please use this

```
var btnClick = true

if(btnClick == true) {
            passwordTextField.isSecureTextEntry = false
        } else {
            passwordTextField.isSecureTextEntry = true
        }
        
        btnClick = !btnClick

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var viewingPassword = true 

@IBAction func btnEyeAction(_ sender: Any) {
     passwordTF.isSecureTextEntry = viewingPassword ? false : true
     viewingPassword.toggle()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated version of [Aimanzaki's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62763285/9389429) which supports **iOS 15.0** and later.

1. Add the following extension for `UITextField`

```
extension UITextField {

    fileprivate func setPasswordToggleImage(_ button: UIButton) {
        var config = UIButton.Configuration.plain()
        if(isSecureTextEntry) {
            config.image = UIImage(systemName: "eye.slash.fill")?.withTintColor(.black, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)
        } else {
            config.image = UIImage(systemName: "eye.fill")?.withTintColor(.black, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)
        }
        config.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 16)
        button.configuration = config
    }

    func enablePasswordToggle(){
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        setPasswordToggleImage(button)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.togglePasswordView), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.rightView = button
        self.rightViewMode = .always
    }

    @IBAction func togglePasswordView(_ sender: Any) {
        self.isSecureTextEntry.toggle()
        setPasswordToggleImage(sender as! UIButton)
    }
}
```

2. Call the extension of your `UITextField` outlet in `viewDidLoad()`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     txtPassword.enablePasswordToggle()
 }
```