# Show password typed by user in UITextfield in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have password `UITextfield` that is currently turned on as secure entry. I would like to show the user the password he has typed inform of text again in the `UITextfield` when the `UISwitch is turned on`. Here is my implementation that so far. It works when i print it out in the console but doesn't in the `UITextfield`. I would like to show it on once the `UISwitch` is turned on and off when the `UISwitch` is turned off.

```
@IBOutlet weak var existingPasswordTexfField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var newPasswordTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var changePasswordSwitch: UISwitch!

@IBAction func showPassword(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    if changePasswordSwitch.isOn {
        guard let oldText = existingPasswordTexfField.text else { return }

        if existingPasswordTexfField.isSecureTextEntry {
            existingPasswordTexfField.text = oldText
        } else {
            print("Pawword is already secure")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to turn off secure entry.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to toggle a UITextField secure text entry (hide password) in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37873119/how-to-toggle-a-uitextfield-secure-text-entry-hide-password-in-swift)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinputtraits/1624427-issecuretextentry) ìsSecureTextEntry is a writable property

So you in your `showPassword` IBAction you need to toggle it at some point :

`existingPasswordTexfField.isSecureTextEntry = false`

or just

`existingPasswordTexfField.isSecureTextEntry = !changePasswordSwitch.isOn`

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to change the `isSecureTextEntry` flag on the textfield when the user flips the switch.

```
@IBAction func showPassword(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    existingPasswordTextField.isSecureTextEntry = changePasswordSwitch.isOn
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is also works

```
existingPasswordTexfField.isSecureTextEntry = changePasswordSwitch.isOn ? false : true
```

Comment: Or simply: `existingPasswordTexfField.isSecureTextEntry = !changePasswordSwitch.isOn`

Comment: This is even better. Thanks.